# Probability with Indicators Textbooks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, characteristic-functions

I am new to using indicator functions (although I am quite familiar with undergrad-level probability and *what* an indicator function is).

I am trying to relearn probability using indicator functions and using them where I think they would be appropriate. But I don't want to use them where they're unconventional. I've been searching for examples for the PMF of a discrete distribution for example. Some say
$$f_{X}(x) = \dfrac{1}{N}\text{, }x = 1, 2, \dots, N$$
but if I were to write it with indicators,
$$f_{X}(x) = \dfrac{1}{N}\mathbf{1}_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}_{\leq N}}(x)\text{, }x\in \mathbb{R}$$
or some strange notation like that. I'm not an expert enough to know which one is more conventional.

Are there probability textbooks that **rely** on indicator functions (preferably at an undergraduate level or at a M.S. level) when explaining PMFs and PDFs, rather than just tossing them off to the side?

Comment: There is nothing magical about indicators to the point that some books would *rely* on them. It's a convenient presentation choice. Some pople use $1_A$, some use $I_A$, some use $\chi_A$, some simply use Iverson's bracket:$[A]$ - $[x\in [1,n]]$ in your example. Two things to remember: $X=\sum_n n[X=n]$ and $E([A])=P(A)$.I can't think of anything else important.

Answer (score 0):

The first form that you have written is *way* much better!

Exactly as you say, we should "avoid strange notation like that". Most of the time we only use them to shorten some specific localized notation that otherwise would be awkward to write in some other manner, say for example inside a specific integral. Personally I have always avoided them, on purpose.